# How do I display fields in my product type in a product display?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have the unique parameters for my product.  Sometimes I want to display some parameters, and sometimes I don't.  So, I defined them in my product type.

My question is how do I display these fields for a product display?  I don't want to create a duplicate when the values are already defined in the product type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields from the referenced product entity are automatically available on the product display node.

Set the fields to visible on the product at

*admin/commerce/products/types/subscription-product/display*

Then, set the fields to display at:

*admin/structure/types/manage/product-display/display*

**Update**: As noted by vintorg below when creating your product reference field on the product display node, ensure "*Render fields from the referenced products when viewing this entity*." is checked.

That should do it.

Comment: The only fields with a visible option (in product type) are the ones already displaying.  The rest of my custom fields in my product type are "Default, Plain Text, Trimmed", etc.

Comment: "Default, Plain Text, Trimmed" aren't fields, they are formatters for specific fields. Can you clarify your question? It sounds as though the fields are already available for display.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, those are my available formatters in my manage display.  It appears they are ready for display, but they don't show up on my product display.

Comment: Also, the fields aren't available in my display.  I'm expecting them to magically display on my product display.  Is that not correct?

Comment: Your product display settings must match the display mode, full, teaser etc..

Comment: I did that, but in my product display, I still don't see the fields from my product type.

Answer (score 0):

When I created my product reference field in my product display, I did not check "Render fields from the referenced products when viewing this entity."

I checked it, and now my product fields now render in my product display.

Comment: Ah yes, I had assumed that was checked. Glad it's sorted.